# Increasing number in base 4

Tags: java, radix

I'm trying to have an integer that is in base 4. I want to increase it to 100 and output it every single time I increase it. Some sample output would be:

```
0
1
2
3
10
11
...
100
```

etc.
How can I do this in java?

Comment: 100(base 4) or 100(base 10) ?

Comment: An integer doesn't have a base. It just has a value representable as a base. Use `Integer#toString` with the appropriate radix value.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Could you give an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In base 4, the numbers 0 to 10 can be determined with [`Integer.toString(int, int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#toString%28int,%20int%29) where the second parameter is the `radix` like

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) { // i < 100 for 1203
    System.out.println(Integer.toString(i, 4));
}
```

Output is

```
0
1
2
3
10
11
12
13
20
21
```

Answer (score 0):

Handle the base 4 conversion on the output. Incrementing the number has no impact due to the bases:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    System.out.println(Integer.toString(i, 4));
```

Outputs:

```
0
1 
2 
3 
10
11
12
13
20
21
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for(int x=0; x<100; x++){
     System.out.println(Integer.toString(x, 4));
}
```

Should do the trick - Integer.toString(x, 4) is the integer as x, the number base 4